# Two comparisons with Excel countif function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue with using countifs function. Basically, I have to compare to columns and count frequency of repeating.
My tables are like:
Product ID: NAME OF PRODUCT, TOTAL PIECES OF PRODUCT, QUANTITY OF PRODUCT. I would like to compare name of products and total pieces with quantity of product is it equal and count how many rows are with those two conditions. 
Thank you for answer

Comment: Give an example. Let's say a table with 10 elements, listing all possible results (including expected output). A screenshot or anything would do

Comment: [Do **not** post screenshots of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and (to @Mark) [do **not** request screenshots of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945) unless an image of sample data explains something that typed data cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).